# How to check in elisp if a string is a substring of another string?

Tags: elisp, string

How to check if a string `s1` is a substring of another string `s2`?

For example `(test-substring "f t" "df tj")  --> t`,
`(test-substring "ft" "df tj")  --> nil`.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The standard Emacs Lisp approach is regular expression matching:

```
(string-match-p (regexp-quote needle) haystack)
```

Answer (score 26):

`cl-search` can do that (and also returns the index of the substring, if found):

```
ELISP> (cl-search "f t" "df tj")
1 (#o1, #x1, ?\C-a)
ELISP> (cl-search "ft" "df tj")
nil
```

Comment: @Name, Has enough time passed?

Answer (score 0):

By the way, I also suggest `string-match`

`(string-match REGEXP STRING &optional START) Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 17.`

`(string-match "12" "14 bla bla 12999")` => 11